# setTitle of collapsing toolbar in other method where it is initialized

Tags: java, android

In my Fragment I have a CollapsingToolbar and it is created it in the `onCreateView()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);

return view;
}
```

Since my title can change in other methods, I tried to create a new method that shall set a new Title of the CollapsingToolbar, but it says `cannot resolve symbol 'collapsingToolbarLayout'`. I tried it like this:

```
public void setTitle(String passedTitle){
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(passedTitle);
}
```

What do I have to change so I can rename the title from other methods?

**Edit:**

This is the class where I use the `setTitle()` method. I try to use it from an inner Class, I tried to cut it as well as possible:

```
public class CallsFragment extends Fragment {

String title;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

public CallsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calls, container, false);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);

    return view;
}


public void setTitle(String passedTitle){
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(passedTitle);
}


public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    //here the title string gets filled     
            Log.d("place", title);
            setTitle(title);
}
}
```

}

And the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

private ViewPager viewPager;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
ChatFragment chatFragment;
CallsFragment callsFragment;
ContactsFragment contactsFragment;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    //Initializing the bottomNavigationView
    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_umkreis:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_karte:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_einstellungen:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            Log.d("page", "onPageSelected: "+position);
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    callsFragment = new CallsFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(callsFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(chatFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(contactsFragment);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    int limit = adapter.getCount();
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause:** Because the `collapsingToolbarLayout` variable is local in `onCreate` method, that why `setTitle` cannot access it.

**Solution:** Make `collapsingToolbarLayout` as a variable of your Fragment.

```
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);

    return view;
}

public void setTitle(String passedTitle){
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(passedTitle);
}
```

**Update:** I see the problem, change the code in **CallsFragment**

From

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);
```

To

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.appBar);
```

**Note:** When you want to access a view from activity that contains current fragment you can use.

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.this_view_inside_activity);
```

If you want to access a view inside the fragment then use.

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View fragmentRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calls, container, false);
View view = fragmentRootView.findViewById(R.id.this_view_inside_fragment);
```

Comment: Can you  help me with an according issue? When I use the setTitle method it always says `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`, but since I printed it to my logcat, the String `title` is not empty. Doesn't it work to set the title like that?

Comment: How do you mean that? I have a String x and it is filled. Then I thought to call setTitle(x)? Why is it a null reference?

Comment: Because `collapsingToolbarLayout` is null that why the app crashes. Make sure the fragment is added to activity before calling `setTitle` method.

Comment: Show the activity code where you use this fragment and `setTitle` method as well.

Comment: I added my fragment where I call the method as well. Do you need the MainActivity with my ViewPager as well?

Comment: Yes if you can add it, I can detect root cause faster.

Comment: I see give me some minutes

Comment: Where do you call `GetContacts` asynstask?

Comment: It can be called from different places, but mainly and where the problem should come from it is called in the fragment inside the `onCreateView()` as well after it is fetching the users gps location

Comment: Are `R.id.toolbar_layout` and `R.id.appBar` from fragment or activity layout?

Comment: From fragment layout and the ViewPager in the main layout

Comment: @user9155899 I added a note to my answer, please take a look.